# Printing picturebox using common dialog prints a blank page

Tags: vb6

I am using the common dialog control to print the contents of a picturebox. Below is my code:

```
 Private Sub mnuFilePrint_Click()

    StopPrinting = False
' Set CancelError is True
On Error GoTo errhandler

    cmndlg.PrinterDefault = True

    ' Set flags
    cmndlg.Flags = cdlPDReturnDC + cdlPDNoPageNums
    cmndlg.ShowPrinter

    pigraph.Picture = picGraph.Image
    Printer.Print picGraph.Picture
    Printer.EndDoc
    Exit Sub
errhandler:
    Select Case Err
    Case 32755 '  Dialog Cancelled
        MsgBox "you cancelled the dialog box"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Unexpected error. Err " & Err & " : " & Error
    End Select

End Sub
```

What happens is once the print button is clicked, the print dialog box opens up and I click print. But the paper I receive is blank, except for a random string of numbers at the top of the page (which changes every time I print).

Anyone have any idea why this problem is occuring? I shouldnt be getting a blank page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that to print the picturebox, the lines:

```
pigraph.Picture = picGraph.Image
Printer.Print picGraph.Picture
```

...are not correct for this situation. They had to be replaced with this line:

```
Printer.PaintPicture picGraph.Image, 0, 0
```

This line prints the picturebox.

Answer (score -1):

To be more specific, pic.picture contains only pictures you have loaded but contains no graphic elements such as line or circle. setting picture= image supplies the graphic elements. strange no documentation tells you this.